# socket.io : How do I call upon my socket methods dynamically from an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have this:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on("action1", function(data){
        socket.emit("action1", data);
    });
    socket.on("action2", function(data){
        socket.emit("action2", data);
    });
    socket.on("action3", function(data){
        socket.emit("action3", data);
    });
});
```

I want this:

```
var socketMethods = {
    action1:function(data, socket){
        socket.emit("action1", data);
    },
    action2:function(data, socket){
        socket.emit("action2", data);
    },
    action3:function(data, socket){
        socket.emit("action3", data);
    }
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    for(key in socketMethods){
        socket.on(key, socketMethods[key]);
    }
});
```

However, I can't pass the socket into the method and I end up with

```
C:\__server\nodejs.js:217
    socket.emit('action1', {msg:"No account"}
               ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'emit' of undefined
```

I have tried passing the socket through the function :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    for(key in socketMethods){
        socket.on(key, function(data, socket){
            socketMethods[key](data, socket);
        });
    }
});
```

The socket doesn't get passed into the function.

How can I call the methods dynamically, and still be able to use socket within the method?

UPDATE:

With this EXACT code:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    for(key in socketMethods){
        socket.on(key, function(data){
            socketMethods[key](data, socket);
        });
    }
});
```

I've found something very interesting.

It DOES work, and I can run socket.emits from the method!

HOWEVER, now, it just runs the LAST method.  In this case, action3 is called no matter what's asked for.  If you ask for action1, or action 2, action 3 is still called.

UPDATE:

Running a console.log(socket._events), I see that the functions error:[function], action1:[function], action2:[function], action3:[function] ARE attached.  When I try to see what's in each of those functions, all I get are.

```
function ack() {
      self.packet({
          type: 'ack'
        , args: io.util.toArray(arguments)
        , ackId: packet.id
      });
    }
```

Regardless of the function I send back to myself. I've also set action2, to be the last thing in the object, and action2 is what is called.  Yet.  When I attached socket.on methods the -normal- way, they look exactly the same in socket._events.

I had a theory that all the methods are being overwritten by the "last" action(action3).

Can't sleep

Comment: I'm not sure it would fix it, but in your final attempt, try just `socket.on(key, function () { socketMethods[key](data, socket); });`. Either way, remember that if you pass `socket` as the second parameter, you'll have to update the methods in the `socketMethods` object to accept the second parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but no dice.

socket.on(key, server.socket[key](data, socket));

ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: Sorry, I didn't recognize something. Look at my answer - I just updated it, and I updated the original text (for the `data` parameter)

Answer (score 0):

The large mistake I made was that I was trying to send the function in assuming that the loop data would always persist.  I was instead receiving a reference of the key data.

I'll have to do more research but instead, we needed to create a function

Figured this out because of this post, thanks to ebohlman

[socket.io Using a for loop to add socket.on methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12969220/socket-io-using-a-for-loop-to-add-socket-on-methods)

```
function makeOn(key) {
  return function(data) {
    dummy.socketMethods[key].call(socket, data);
  }
}

for(key in dummy.socketMethods){
  socket.on(key, makeOn(key));
}
```