# socket.io Using a for loop to add socket.on methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Assume

```
socketMethods:{
    update:function(data){
        this.emit("test", data);
        console.log("socket.update");
    },
    test:function(data){
        this.emit("test", data);
        console.log("socket.test");
    }
}
```

This below is possible, and allows me to emit "test" and "update", and "test" and "update" will be called

```
socket.on("test", function(data){
    dummy.socketMethods.test.call(socket, data);
});
socket.on("update", function(data){
    dummy.socketMethods.update.call(socket, data);
});
```

These below are NOT possible...  EACH one will instead call "test", if I emit "test" OR "update".  If I use a FOR loop, all methods will become the "last" method called.

That is:  If I switched update and test so that test is first, and update is second in the socketMethods object.  "update" would always be called, regardless of whether I asked for "test" or "update"

```
for(key in dummy.socketMethods){
    socket.on(key, function(data){
        dummy.socketMethods[key].call(socket, data);
    });
}



var methods = ["test", "update"];
while(methods.length !== 0){
    var method = methods.pop();
    console.log(method);
    socket.on(method, function(data){
        dummy.socketMethods[method].call(socket, data);
    });
}



var methods = ["test", "update"];
for(var i = 0; i < methods.length; i++){
    console.log(i);
    socket.on(methods[i], function(data){
        console.log(i);
        dummy.socketMethods[methods[i]].call(socket, data);
    });
}
```

CLUE : The for loop using 'i', has two console.logs.  The second console.log returns "2"

Why does this happen?  And how could I use a for loop to attach my socketMethods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making the common mistake of assuming that a closure "traps" the *value* of an outer function's variable at the time it was *created*. It doesn't. It "traps" a *reference* to the outer function's variable, and its value will be whatever the outer variable has at the time the closure is *executed*. If you're creating closures in a loop, that value will be whatever it had at the end of the loop.

The way to get around this is to create an "enclosing" closure that uses the outer variable's value as argument. One way to do this is to create a helper function that generates your closure. In your first example, you could do

```
function makeOn(key) {
  return function(data) {
    dummy.socketMethods[key].call(socket, data);
  }
}

for(key in dummy.socketMethods){
  socket.on(key, makeOn(key));
}
```

Now in each closure, `key` will be a newly-created variable (differing between closures) set to the appropriate value.

It's also possible to use an immediate function call (what some call a "self-executing function") to do the same thing a little more succinctly, but also somewhat less readably.

Comment: I don't think I can even -begin- to express how much I'm going to study closures because of this post.  This worked -instantly-, didn't even have to run it twice.